# Rival Crock-Pot temp settings

Tags: crockpot

My old Rival Crock-Pot (4.5 qt?) has only OFF, LOW, and HIGH temp settings.
I'm making crock-pot chicken confit with hindquarters. The recipe directs me to set it on the LOW setting for 3 hours, then 1.5-2 hours on HIGH. At about 2 hours into the LOW setting, the oil has come to a moderately-rolling boil.
Should oil even reach a *low* boil on the LOW setting?

Comment: I very much doubt it's oil that's boiling, more like water-based juices from the chicken.  Unless you have a house full of smoke, that is, but I reckon you would have said

Comment: It is the oil boiling.

Comment: What type of oil is it? I'm rather doubtful it'd the oil boiling because from what I can tell that'd have to be nearly 200 C, which seems unlikely for the low setting - how can you confirm it is the oil boiling?

Comment: If that's true, you should probably unplug it before you start a fire, and replace it. It shouldn't get anywhere near hot enough to commonboil oil.  However just because there are bubbles coming out of a pot of oil doesn't mean the oil itself is boiling.  If you have a food thermometer you might want to stick it in.  But all cooking oils in routine use smoke well before they boil - no smoke means it's not the oil boiling.  Sorry to be pedantic but the difference is significant, and any recipe I can find *will* let some water into the oil

Comment: Apparently there is no longer a LOW temp setting on my crock pot. I have no idea how that might have happened. We're both old. meh

Comment: Yes, but even "high" shouldn't get halfway to boiling oil (which smokes around 200°C/300°F but doesn't boil until 300°Cor 600°F)